# Android studio - kotlin: Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileJava' (21) and 'compileKotlin' (1.8)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, jvm

I'm doing a project in a course for multi module project and I walked into a problem.

when trying to sync the gradle it throw me the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileKotlin'. 
Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileJava' (21) and 'compileKotlin' (1.8).
```

what does it means? I couldn't find any answer on internet. Tried to solve it in different ways and couldn't get it to work.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

If you are using latest **`JDK 21`** to your project then you can make changes in `build.gradle(app-level)`

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}
```

and

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '21'
}
```

and your project will run successfully

Comment: how do I know if I run JDK 21?

Comment: asking again :)

Comment: I can see it from the error. by the way can you please edit your question with complete gradle file